# fsharp compound interest beginner

Tags: f#

I do not know what I'm supposed to do here  I am a beginner

```
let interest = 0.02     // Interest rate is 2%

let periods = 12.0      // Number of times the interest is compounded per year

let years = 10.0        // Number of years the money is borrowed for


// Calculate compound interest using the formula from:
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound_Interest

let compound investment = 
    ***I am supposed to put something here***

let res = compound 1000.0

shouldEqual (round res) 1221.0

printfn "Compound interest (full): %f" res

printfn "Compound interest (two digits): %.2f" res
```

Comment: You need to put your method for calculating the compound interest there

Comment: do you understand the formula (from wikipedia)? Where exactly is your problem? Please try it, look at the errors you might get and ask again with more than the mere copy&paste of your homework-exercise ;)

Comment: a small hint: you can use `Math.Pow` but you might find it easier to write something like `2.0**3.0` but make sure to use floats (another hint: all that is given you here are floats) ;)

Answer (score 1):

If i you right understand:

```
let interest = 0.02     // Interest rate is 2%
let periods = 12.0      // Number of times the interest is compounded per year
let years = 10.0        // Number of years the money is borrowed for
let investment = 1000.0     //principal amount (initial investment)

// Calculate compound interest using the formula from:
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound_Interest
let compound P j n t = 
    P*((1.0+j/n)**(n*t))

let res = compound investment interest periods years

//shouldEqual (round res) 1221.0 ? What this?

printfn "Compound interest (full): %f" res
printfn "Compound interest (two digits): %.2f" res
```

But I'm surprised that I saw this question here

Comment: why are you surprised - people post their homework all the time (and it is ok) - normally we only give hints at first though ;) - so don't expect to much upvotes ^^

Comment: @Carsten König. Thanks for explanation. Next time I will see question, i also try to push to the solution. I'm rather surprised that somewhere teaching F#, not C++, C# or Python. Upvotes are not important for me. Although it's a offensively when put a "-" :) . I recently started learning F #, so I'm wondering how you can solve more problems, even the most simple. Sorry for my English

Comment: @Foggy Finder: Try the F# Koans, try to solve rosetta stone problems, or even better find a OSS project you like and contribute to it?

Comment: I'm taking a beginner course and they expected me to understand how to do this but I do not. I think the course teachings are simple but when they ask you to do  task its quite a jump in what it expects from you.

Comment: @streetfighting man, Now you understood how solved your problem?